# Navigation bar not appeared?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I am using XCode 4.

In My application simple View Based Application.

I have no UINavigation controller allocated.

But I just want to use default property of UINAvigation controller.

I have done in

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
   // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem=self.bbiAdd;

    [super viewDidLoad];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

But I can not see the result ...
I have done with interface builder with this code....

Comment: If you dont have a UINavigationController set up, how can you call self.navigationcontroller? You will have to allocate one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use the `self.navigationController` if you don't have an `UINavigationController`.

All you can do is add an `UINavigationBar` to your `UIViewController`.

Comment: As I have seen it in the Interface Builder view has property, So I have set it.?

Comment: The property in the IB is just there to show you what the view will look like if a UINavigationController is used. It will not add any thing to your view

Answer (score 1):

Just Drag and Drop a UINavigationBar in your XIB, set the Title (if you want) for it and you are good to go.